# samba ubuntu and ipad

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, ipad

I have a pc running ubuntu 20.04 and an ipad with the latest iOS as of today.

`sudo apt install samba
sudo useradd tarosson
sudo passwd tarosson
sudo smbpasswd -a tarosson`

After running the codes above, I added the following lines at the end of /etc/samba/smb.conf

`[share1]
comment = A Shared Directory
path = /home/taro/tarosson
valid users = taro tarosson
public = no
writable = yes
read only = no`

And when I try to access this "share1" through the ipad's Files app, it is read only and cannot upload the files on my ipad.
Is the problem coming from that I made the shared directory in the user taro's home directory?
Can you please tell me what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: Who is accessing share1? taro or tarosson? And what are the permissions of the shared directory. `ls -dl /home/taro/torosson`

Comment: @Morbius1drwxrwx--- is the result and tarosson is accessing from iPad.

Comment: Add `vfs object = fruit streams_xattr` to the global share of your `smb.conf` and restart samba, disconnect and reconnect from your ipad and you should then be able to upload just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your share definition to this:

```
[share1]
comment = A Shared Directory
path = /home/taro/tarosson
valid users = taro tarosson
force user = taro
public = no
writable = yes
read only = no
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

When tarosson provides the correct credentials to samba for this share `force user = taro` will make him appear to be taro - at least for this share. So if taro has write access to the /home/taro/tarosson folder on the Ubuntu system so will tarosson.